# Why does the compiler keeps telling me (forever) to rerun because labels have changed?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings, acronyms, elsarticle

I have a LaTeX paper (multifile setup, using `\input{}` statements) that , since a few days ago, keeps telling me at each compile (both with `pdflatex` or `latex`):

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right
```

Even recompiling, say, ten times does not fix it. All references in the paper seems fine, though (can't be 100% sure, would need to check each and every `\ref` in the source with the PDF output).

It's probably because I misplaced a label or reference in some way. But how to find it, and fix the issue? What sort of misplacements result in this repeated message?

**Edit:** I've tracked it down to an issue with the `acronym` package in combination with using `\ac{}` in the abstract definition of an [elsarticle](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class) (Elsevier's latex class, I am using the latest version, i.e. 1.20b from 2009-09-17) document. Below is a minimal copy/paste example where the issue appears:

```
\documentclass[final,5p, times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass{article} --> no problem when using this one (and removing frontmatter)
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        \begin{abstract}
                This is just a sentence with an acronym in it: \ac{ICT}.
        \end{abstract}
    \end{frontmatter}

    \acrodef{ICT}{Information and Communication Technologies}
\end{document}
```

It is not clear to me if this is because of a bug in the acronym package, or elsarticle.

Comment: I have seen things like that when people used `\ref{}` in things like margin notes. At every recompile the note jumped between two pages, always leaving changed references... So the answer is "yes", you must have done something. It is nearly impossible to tell you what you did wrong. My advice is to do the classic: Comment some inputs, does it go away? Can you find the one input for which the warning appears? or are those multiple inputs? once you found the input, comment parts of that file to pin point where the problem occurs.

Comment: are there any other warnings (about duplicate labels for example). Otherwise run latex save the `.aux` file to a different name run latex again and compare the difference between the old and new aux files.

Comment: **@Martin**: using commenting inputs, I figured out the problem is attributed to the use of `\ac{}`  (from the acronym package) in my abstract. Removing them makes it work (which is OK for me, as I  did an `\acresetall` after the abstract anyway). Usage of acronyms in the other parts of the paper doesn't give this problem, weird.
**@David**: both `.aux` fields are identical, also weird

Comment: @Rabarberski we don't like to leave qns unanswered do you want to self-answer or should we close too-localised or do you want to leave open and see if someone can debug acronym. Your choice but if you want the last it would help if you could add a small complete document that shows the problem now you havee narrowed it down.

Comment: @David: I've inserted a small complete document where the problem occurs. Might indeed be too localized, but still, could be of interest to other people running into the same problem.

Comment: `elsarticle` collects the `abstract` inside a box. Though, I have no idea why this should affect things. The `frontmatter` env just adds `\maketitle` at the end.

Comment: When I compile the above example with `article` instead of `elsarticle`, the `.aux` file has `\reset@newl@bel` as its second line.  This is the `acronym` package's way of preventing an incorrect label-changed warning.  But with `elsarticle`, the use of the `frontmatter` and `abstract` environments puts something earlier in the `.aux` file, including a line that defines a label.  Perhaps this is a bug in `acronym`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a bad interaction with the `\twocolumn` command, and so is a more general problem that just for the `elsarticle` class.  Here is a minimal example triggering the error:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[Heading with acronym \ac{ICT}]{
Some text.}

\acrodef{ICT}{Information and Communication Technologies}
\end{document}
```

As @Jouhn Collins notices the `.aux` file now has `\reset@new@label` placed too late:

```
\relax 
\undonewlabel{acro:ICT}
\newlabel{acro:ICT}{{}{1}}
\acronymused{ICT}
\reset@newl@bel
\newacro{ICT}[ICT]{Information and Communication Technologies}
```

A work around is to add a macro that writes `\reset@new@label` out to the `.aux` file.  (I am very reluctant to meddle with the definition of `\twocolumn`.  Trying to this at `\begin{document}` is too late.)  Here is such a fix, first in the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extraclearlabels}{\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
  \string\reset@newl@bel
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\extraclearlabels Heading with acronym \ac{ICT}]{
Some text.}

\acrodef{ICT}{Information and Communication Technologies}
\end{document}
```

and now in the original example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extraclearlabels}{\protected@write\@auxout{}{%
  \string\reset@newl@bel
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
  \begin{abstract}
    \extraclearlabels
    This is just a sentence with an acronym in it: \ac{ICT}.
  \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

In text acronym \ac{ICT}.

\acrodef{ICT}{Information and Communication Technologies}
\end{document}
```