# How to diagnose a permanent "Label(s) may have changed" warning?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

I'm getting the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

The problem is, it doesn't go away after rerunning (any number of times).

The document in question is over 200 pages long and includes about 30 packages, so it's not really feasible for me to provide a minimal example. But I know my own code pretty well. I can probably fix it if I knew a bit more about the problem. So I want to ask some general questions:

- How does the "labels changed; rerun" mechanism work, anyway?
- Is there a common culprit responsible for this problem?
- How would someone generally go about diagnosing it?

I've read the following question:

- [Why does the compiler keeps telling me (forever) to rerun because labels have changed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109178/why-does-the-compiler-keeps-telling-me-forever-to-rerun-because-labels-have-ch)

But I'm not using the `elsarticle` or `acronym` packages, so the accepted answer didn't apply to me.

---

**More info:** As suggested, I did a kind of 'commenting out' binary search. (By the way, if LaTeX knows that labels may have changed, why can't it tell me *which* labels?)

Anyway, I seemed to track down the problem to a specific `figure`. When I compile only chapters 1 to 3, removing that figure also removes the warning. However, if I once again include all chapters, removing that `figure` isn't enough. So I guess there are other problem locations. But I don't have time to search chapters 4 to 9 right now...

I can also tell you this: I have a `tmp` directory where LaTeX and friends dump all temporary files. And between two compilations, the relevant content of this directory does not change *at all*. That is to say, `diff -r` tells me that the only changes are some timestamps and the `.pdf` file. In particular: all `.aux` files are identical.

Comment: Did you try to delete `aux` file?

Comment: An orthogonal fix : One of my favorite TeXperts Paul Isambert wrote `silence` with an entertaining manual. Look at `yax` too while you are at it which is slowly replacing `pgfkeys` for me.

Comment: The possible culprit might be some float that keeps changing its position due to the previous recalculation and it never stops doing so. Something like, *when in 0 go to 1, when in 1 go to 0*.

Comment: Did you try the method of dividing the input into two in order to find the part that's responsible for the changing label?

Comment: The divide and "concur" can only work to a certain extent in this case. You can find by this method the shortest prefix of the code in which the problem occurs. The jumpy reference should occur at the end of this prefix. But, it could be that the jumpiness is a result of numbered reference, which, e.g., changes from three digits to four if the file is long enough.

Comment: Check if the `varioref` package is used. It's a common culprit for this kind of behaviour. The only fix would be to use a normal `\ref` at the point that's responsible or change the text slightly so the `\vref` isn't at a page boundary anymore. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#The_varioref_package

Comment: Hi all. I updated my question with new information. (1) @Sigur: While testing I routinely remove all `.aux` files, so that's not it.

Comment: (2) @percusse: That's very useful, thanks! :-) But for now I'm just worried that some reference is *actually* shifting around in my document.

Comment: (3) @PauloCereda: Take a look at my extended answer. The auxiliary files stay identical between compiles. To add to that: the figure in question does not move in the `.pdf`.

Comment: (4) @egreg: Check my extended answer. I did, and tracked (part of) it down to a specific figure. But I'm still not sure how this figure could be responsible!

Comment: (5) @Christian: Thanks for the suggestion. `varioref` is not used by me, directly or indirectly. However, I do use `cleveref` extensively.

Comment: The fact that removing the figure and reinstating the missing chapter makes the problem reappear might mean that you have *two* similar situations.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. But let's pretend for the moment that my document is only three chapters long. How could the presence of this figure be responsible for the warning, given that when present it remains firmly in place, and the auxiliary files don't change at all between compilations? Perhaps if I know the answer, I won't have to repeat my binary search in chapters 4 to 9. The process takes a long time, especially for later chapters. As @ YossiGil said, I have to keep the whole prefix for every test.

Comment: `cleveref` shouldn't be an issue since it doesn't change the reference text depending on the relative position of the reference and the referenced object as `varioref` does (and which can therefore cause such problems).

Comment: what packages are you actually using?  when testing footmisc, i was able to construct a pathological per-page footnote arrangement that caused this diagnostic.  it rather sounds as if your figures aren't (really) at fault.

Comment: Relevant: [Understanding how references and labels work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764)

Comment: I had a similar problem when using hyperref and a figure caption which contained an active character.  The problem was that hyperref (and rerunfilecheck) compared the caption and the caption written to a file (with expansion), and that my home-brewed active character was not robust.  Perhaps your figure caption contains a fragile command?

Comment: Run a compile a few times. Copy your .aux file. Rerun the compile again, and then compare the .aux files.

Comment: Are your figures in floating environments or are they fixed? I would try making them all fixed environments -- try redefining the figure environment so that it does nothing. Floats shouldn't move from one compile to the next, but I've always thought that floats were a little random so I'm inclined to (unfairly) blame them.

Comment: @Andrew: Worth a try, thanks. :-) I had to put this problem on the back burner for a while, but it's time I did something about it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> (By the way, if LaTeX knows that labels may have changed, why can't it tell me which labels?)

The following document will give the re-run error message each time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter


% \def\@testdef #1#2#3{%
%   \def\reserved@a{#3}\expandafter \ifx \csname #1@#2\endcsname
%  \reserved@a  \else
% \typeout{^^Jlabel #2 changed:^^J%
% \meaning\reserved@a^^J%
% \expandafter\meaning\csname #1@#2\endcsname^^J}%
% \@tempswatrue \fi}


\begin{document}
\providecommand\r@foo{{1}{1}}
\edef\@currentlabel{.\expandafter\@firstoftwo\r@foo}
\label{foo}
a

\end{document}
```

produces a log

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

If you uncomment the block in the preamble you get an additional diagnostic telling you which label has changed, and the old and new definition:

```
label foo changed:
macro:->{............1}{1}
macro:->{...........1}{1}

)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Comment: Awesome. :-) Will try this when I get home.

Comment: Thanks to this diagnostic trick, I was finally able to fix the issue. It turns out, the captions of all offending labels had inline math with a `_` (subscript) inside (though the before/after versions were always identical). Replacing these was all I had to do! --- I am unable to reproduce this in a minimal document. Can't say I'm surprised. I hacked around in my thesis code so much, it's hardly LaTeX anymore. --- Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This diagose does not always work. I still get an infinite loop without any hints.

Comment: @user877329 can't really say anything to a small comment, if you can make a reproducible example, please ask a new question, posting the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you know a trick that works regardless of what packages you have, regardless of situation, post it. Your trick works for the first two runs, but fails on all remaining. I use harvard varioref hyperref cleveref glossaries (in that order).

Comment: @user877329 without an example demonstrating the problem I couldn't even start to guess:-)

Comment: @user877329 a new question with a test case is probably more likely to make it easier to solve your problem than a bounty. As it is I can't guess why this answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: For completeness, the example should also call `\makeatother` after the commented code.

Comment: This is a life-saver. In my case it turns out I have some character in the caption that LaTeX doesn't like ...

Comment: Is it reasonable to leave this diagnostic code turned on all the time, for a large document (hundreds of pages)?

Comment: @NormanRamsey I guess so, it's my code so it must be safe, I think... (I can't see any real downsides)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too.  I used David's excellent little snippet to catch changed references.  Since the log file is very long, I grepped them out with:

```
$ egrep -A2 "label .* changed:" jobname.log
```

In my case, I found that the unstable labels were of the form `pgfidnnnn`, which I believe come from using the TikZ key `remember picture`.  And they weren't changing by much.  Per the manual's suggestion, I had placed `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` in my document's preamble.  I shut off this blanket option and the unstable labels disappeared.

Comment: In my case it was the \linegoal macro from the linegoal packet which repeatedly jumped between two calculations of the remaining line width. Using a hardcoded width instead of linegoal fixed it thanks do David's code!

Comment: In my case it was the `breqn` package.

Answer (score 1):

@Onner Irotsab In my case, it was also `breqn` but why would this package cause this 'Label(s) changed warning' message?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/242770)