# Repeated "Label(s) may have changed" when using \catcode`_=12 underscore hack with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, labels, catcodes

This MWE produces repeated `Label(s) may have changed` warnings despite the output files not changing. The same problem has been discussed in [How to diagnose a permanent "Label(s) may have changed" warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154594/), but lacking an MWE could only symptomatically be solved (by removing the underscore from the `\caption`). Now, I do not want to remove the underscore from the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`_=12
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
    \mathcode`_="8000
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{$x_y$}
    \label{z}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

An even more minimal MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\catcode`_=12
\begin{figure}
    \caption{$x_y$}
    \label{z}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Some background: I use the

```
\catcode`_=12
```

hack after the discussion (and egreg's answer) at [Underscore in textmode vs mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/), among other things, to allow use of underscores in DOIs and `bibtex` keys. But it seems to interfere with hyperref and captions.

What can I do?

Comment: This stems from the fact that you're changing the `\catcode` *within* the `document` environment, and that the `.aux` is usually read `\AtBeginDocument`. So, there's no correspondence between the `_` read in by the `.aux` and written out by `\caption`.

Comment: Oh. So you mean I can simply move the `\catcode` before `\begin{document}` and be done? Seems to work. So what is the `\AtBeginDocument{...}` for then? Just to prevent the `\catcode` from interfering with anything else in the preamble? Is there anything such as `\BeforeBeginDocument`?

Comment: [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides some environment hooks which you can use (like `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{document}{<stuff>}` and `\AtBeginEnvironment{document}{<stuff>}`).

Comment: Someone else might try that, egreg's answer works for me. Thanks anyway! Just to add that `\AfterEndPreamble` from `etoolbox` did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve the issue. The `_` will have the right category code when the `.aux` file is read at begin document. I believe the problem is in the fact that arguments are grabbed “too soon” when `hyperref` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \catcode`_=12
    \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
    \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
    \mathcode`_="8000
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`_=12 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{$x_y$}
    \label{z}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does! What else can I say? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the only thing that seems to be required is in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\catcode`_=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
\immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`_=12 }
\catcode`^=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`^
\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sp
\mathcode`^="8000
\immediate\write\@auxout{\catcode`^=12 }
}
\makeatother
```

Note that I have also experienced problems (less reproducibly) with equations
that have superscripts in them. Hence the ^ case as well. I don't know why that seems to need the mathcode reset when the _ case doesn't. Probably one should include it in both.