# How does LaTeX know the page number of a reference?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am creating documents with various references, citations, an index, table of contents, and other linked elements. How does LaTeX know how to properly cross reference a page while properly formatting a page and keeping the page numbers correct?

How does Latex know that inserting a page reference won't modify the page of the referenced label?

For example, if I reference a section later in my document with `\ref{sec:bestsection}` then LaTeX must figure out later what page `\label{sec:bestsction}` is on and then go back and insert that into the `\ref` position on the second compile (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111281/25208)).

However, suppose I have a large document and it happens that the `sec:bestsection` is on page *10230*. Also, suppose that this large page number happens to add enough space to the document that it pushes another word off the end of the page. One thing leads to another, and now `sec:bestsection` is on page *10231*.

How does LaTeX know that this happened and not use the wrong page number? Does it always assume that a `\ref` will fit on the line?

Comment: Related: [How to diagnose a permanent “Label(s) may have changed” warning?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154594/how-to-diagnose-a-permanent-labels-may-have-changed-warning). The change in pages you note can lead to an infinite loop if the right combination of bad luck hits you.

Comment: It doesn't.  Values from the previous run are used.  For almost all cases they tend to stabilize.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer to your question in the title is “LaTeX *doesn't* know”, at least not completely.

## How does LaTeX manage cross-references?

Suppose you have

```
As we shall see in section~\ref{sec!main-results}, ...

...[many pages later]...

\section{Main results}\label{sec!main-results}

We are now ready to prove the most important theorems.
```

When the `\label` is seen, the page with `\ref` has long been typeset and output: there's no way to “get back and fix the number”.

So the approach is not “get all the cross references right at once”, because it would need keeping the whole document in memory, before doing any typesetting. Instead, LaTeX writes a note as soon as it outputs a page where a `\label` command appeared: in the `.aux` file you'll find something like

```
\newlabel{sec!main-results}{{3}{9}}
```

where the first number is the section number and the second one is the page number. The note is written out only when shipping out a page, because only then the page number is really known. Remember that TeX always looks ahead and only typesets full paragraphs, before deciding for a page break.

At the end of the job, the `.aux` file is closed and input. At such time `\newlabel` gets a suitable definition, whose purpose is to check whether the label was already known from a previous run and, in this case, whether one of the associated numbers has changed.

This is the point where you can see warnings such as

```
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right

There were multiply-defined labels

Label `<label>' multiply defined
```

that should be self-explanatory.

At the start of a job, when LaTeX is processing `\begin{document}`, the `.aux` file is input and `\newlabel` gets a different definition, which allows for `\ref{sec!main-results}` or `\pageref{sec!main-results}` to print the proper number. But what number? In the case above, the section number will be 3, even in case you have added a whole section between runs. Only at the end of the job, LaTeX will know the number has changed and it will issue the first of the warnings listed above.

If a cross-reference is unknown, just `??` will be printed and the warning about changed label will be issued. If a `\ref` or `\pageref` command refers to a label not yet defined, you get the warning

```
There were undefined references
```

but also

```
Reference `<label>' on page <page> undefined
```

that will tell you that, maybe, you have misspelled the label.

## Should we care about the size of a cross-reference?

Should we care about the space used by the reference? Not really. Paragraphs usually have enough flexibility to allow for shrinking or stretching a line without modifying substantially the output. This is not completely foolproof and there are examples around of cleverly written documents that never stabilize: each new run of LaTeX will change the page number associated to a label so it never remains the same. However, the chances that this happens in a real document are pretty small.

## What about multiple runs?

Document processors such as `latexmk` are able to look into the `.log` file for warnings about changed labels or undefined references and trigger a new run for fixing the output. However it's not so important that at each point in time the cross-references are correct: they'll be when you get no warning like the ones above.

## What about the `.aux` file?

The `.aux` file is used for several other purposes: citations, for example, but also other administrative tasks. Packages, notably `hyperref`, can modify the annotations made, by extending the syntax for the two versions of `\newlabel`, but dealing with this would be too long. The idea is still the same.

Important note. It's clear from this description, that preserving the integrity of the `.aux` file between runs is *essential*. This file should generally not be removed, unless it has become corrupt because of some fatal error. An incomplete annotation might cause an error when the file is input: interrupting the LaTeX run at this error will preserve the same corrupt file, so at the next run the same error will reappear. In such cases, removing the `.aux` file is the only remedy. Not a big deal, it will cost a new run of LaTeX (maybe two). But, of course, removing a correct `.aux` file at the end of a run will *always* produce errors about undefined reference.

Finally, there is a switch that makes LaTeX not touch any of the file it writes out: if you add `\nofiles` in the preamble, the `.aux` file and the ones used for the table of contents and similar lists will only be input and not rewritten. It's a relic of the past, when even writing to a file or just keeping some open caused delays, so when one was sure that cross-reference and lists were correct, adding `\nofiles` saved some running time. Nowadays, the overhead is so small that such a trick is almost useless.

Answer (score 18):

It writes page numbers of all references to the aux file. Note that on the first run, when there is no aux file, it puts ?? instead. On later runs, it first reads the aux file. Then, as it makes note of page numbers, it will compare the page number to what was written to the aux file on the previous run. If any references differ, it will issue a warning at the end of the run.

It is conceivable, though, that this process will never terminate. As the number of digits in the page number goes up, it is conceivable (barely) that the paragraph will become a line *shorter*, due to the way the paragraph building algorithm works. And that could, in turn, move the referenced page one page back, shortening the page number once more. But I think you'll have to work really hard to come up with an example of this.

If you number your pages with roman numerals, it is a bit easier: Now a later page number can have a shorter number, which more plausibly shortens the paragraph by a line.

Answer (score 14):

This is why you need to latex two or three (or more times) if you latex `myfile.tex` then look in `myfile.aux` and you will see all the cross reference information. So on the first run references are just `?` but after that it uses the values written out the previous time.  At the end of the run latex does a consistency check that the values it has written are the same as the ones read in, if they are different it issues the "labels have changed, re-run LaTeX" warning.

Comment: It is strange, in my opinion, that LaTeX uses `\thepage` when `\newlabel` is used. This means that the numeric value could be entirely lost, (if `\thepage` is has been redefined for whatever purpose).  I guess this is another remnant of those harsh days of computers in the eighties with little memory. (I meant: redundant information with both the value of the numeric counter and `\thepage` would be more satisfying).

Comment: @jfbu what else should it be using. Say you have a reference to an equation in the frontmatter, then the page reference should of course reflect the current numbering scheme. I agree however that it would be nice if we could gather much more info, something like zref for example

Comment: @jfbu for both pageref and ref latex just stores the print form, theire need not actually be an underlying counter at all in the case of ref. hyperref (and nameref) etc extend it with storing the name and Heiko's zref extends it with storing the number, but as you say, space was tight in 1985..

Comment: when I said counter in my comment I meant the page counter. Recently I had a document where I redefined `\thepage` as a quick an easy way without modifying the footer to get some info at the usual page number location. But I had to find a way around the fact that `\pageref` would use that as well. About the `nameref`, `zref`,... packages, this is the whole problem of LaTeX2e and the packages; very successful up to some point. Probably LaTeX3 will have an altogether differing development model for the next centuries.

Comment: @jfbu that's the plan:-)