# Using varioref and cleveref, does cleveref diagnose a document that LaTeX always wants to re-run?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, warnings, varioref

I've got a large document that LaTeX always wants to re-run.  Using the technique described at
[How to diagnose a permanent "Label(s) may have changed" warning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154594/how-to-diagnose-a-permanent-labels-may-have-changed-warning), I traced the problem to some `\vref`s.  But I expected the problematic `\vref`s to be flagged for me by the `varioref` package.  The documentation for package `varioref` states,

> Defining commands like the ones described above poses some interesting problems.
>   Suppose, for example, that a generated text like ‘on the next page’ gets broken
>   across pages. If this happens it is very difficult to find an acceptable solution and
>   in fact can even result in a document that will always change from one state to an-
>   other (i.e., inserting one string, finding that this is wrong, inserting another string
>   on the next run which makes the first string correct again, inserting . . . ). The
>   current implementation of varioref therefore issues an error message whenever
>   the generated text is broken across page boundaries, e.g.,
>
> ```
> table 5 on the current hpage break i page
> ```
>
> would would result in an error, which needs to be resolved by the user by replacing
>   the `\vref` command with an ordinary `\ref` just before the final run. This is not
>   completely satisfactory but in such case no solution really is.

The `cleveref` package, which I have (correctly) loaded after `varioref`, claims that it implements `\vref` correctly.  But is `cleveref` supposed to replicate this diagnostic capability?  I need to figure out whether to report a bug or a feature request, and to what maintainer :-)

I have tried and failed to produce a MWE that has a `\vref` in exactly the  right place to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "diagnosis". As you note, `cleveref` makes some changes to the innards of `varioref` so that `\vref` works "as expected" if `cleveref` is loaded too. (Aside: Loading `cleveref` also resolves some deep-seated conflicts between `varioref` and `hyperref`.) But "as expected" contains the caveat that page-related labels may change from run to run without ever settling down. It is not the job of `cleveref` -- and the package certainly makes no claim to this effect -- to improve on the job `varioref`'s does and come up with a better page-related algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cleveref` disables the checking for cross-references being broken across pages when redefining the `varioref` commands for its own use. So you can argue it is `cleveref`s fault, but there is a reason for this in the current implementation of the package.

I'm currently working with Toby to get to a better co-existence between the two packages and also with the `hyperref` package. Once this is in place, such issues should be correctly diagnosed again.

The `varioref` improvements for this will probably not make it into the fall release of LaTeX, but should become available with the winter release.

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/174